# My Preview Text Keeps Truncating a Character

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, dom-events, haml

Pretty confused on this one. Built out a simple input form with a corresponding preview (it's essentially creating a survey), but for some reason the preview text on the right never reveals the last character. Check out the screenshot: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s144/sh/f1c45522-6bcd-4241-aae8-70497c4bc757/3888c44d7c34481ce791974551fbcda0/res/832f002a-57ab-4d35-8233-455cd8a5d247/skitch.png)

Here's the code for the input:

```
    .control-group
      %label.control-label for="product-name" 
         Product Name&nbsp;
         %a#help-campaign-product.icon-question-sign title="The name of the product or service whose features you are trying to value. Your survey respondents will see this."
      .controls
         %input#product-name.input-xlarge.required type="text" name="product-name" placeholder="My Product" value="{% if campaign.product_name %}{{ campaign.product_name }}{% endif %}"
```

and the code for the preview:

```
    #campaign-title
      .wrapper
        %h4#campaign-product-name style="text-align:center; font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-weight:300; font-size:24px;"
          My Product
    #preview-product-description style="display:none;"
      %h4#campaign-headline style="text-align:center; font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif; font-weight:300; font-size:24px;"
```

I'm pretty stumped. :(

Comment: Evernote shows an error message "access denied" and wants me to login. Care to add the code in question and maybe add a http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the computed CSS of `#campaign-title`, `.wrapper` and `h4`. It seems like you have a fixed width and overflow:hidden.

Comment: You are probably updating the preview title too early, e.g. onkeydown or onkeypress? You should use onkeyup.

Comment: @acoiro That's exactly what it was. Thanks so much for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here was highlighted by @acoiro best here. Essentially, we were updating the preview title on "onkeydown" which wasn't allowing the actual character to register in the preview. Changing the function to "onkeyup" fixed everything.